# Residuals are normally distributed

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis, statistics

I did not know whether to post this question in the Physics or Statistics section of StackExchange, but the question involves the application of statistics to the analysis of experimental results.

I was told that, when a measurement is taken, each error in that measurement can be assumed to have the same probability distribution and independent of each other. This then allows us to apply the CLT, and conclude that the residuals (when compared to a model) are normally distributed (given there are 'enough' random error variables). The independence assumption intuitively seems valid, but the identical probability distribution I need more convincing on, what allows us to make this assumption? (I believe this is called the i.i.d. assumption?)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need that they are identically distributed, it is just easier to proof if you use that assumption. More generally you only need that none of the single errors is dominating your experiment. In mathemtical terms:
$$ \lim\limits_{N\rightarrow0} \frac{\text{Var}(X_i)}{\text{Var}(\hat{X})} =0 \quad \forall\; i$$
$$\hat{X} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^N X_i$$
This is intuitively clear. Think of a situation where you have several minor sources of error and one major source of error. The distribution of the measurement error will be determined by the distribution of the main source.